# CCnet MsBuild and MSTest

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, mstest

I've set up a CCNet Server with MSBuild and MSTest.
Afterwards I've created a Test Project with some Unit Tests.
The Build is sucessfull, but two of the Unit Tests do fail (on purpose).
I receive an Email that the Build was not successfull (even only the Unit Tests failed). 
Is it possible to send a seperated Email (if only the Unit Tests fail) or change the contend of the Email so I can see that only the Unit Tests failed and not the Build itsself?

I look forward to your answer,
with kind regards

Sandor D.

Comment: Skimming the documentation I don't think so, no - I think they're both treated as the same failure event. CC.NET is open source though so it ought be possible to enhance this. You can, although I forget exactly how, include build logs and test logs in the email so you should be able to see from the email contents which went wrong.

Comment: Okay, thank you so far.
Would be nice if sb could tell me how to. 
And also if its possible to change the content of the Email!

Answer (score 0):

I've appended my ccnet.config with the following code:

```
<email>
...
<xslFiles>
  <xslFile>xsl\header.xsl</xslFile>
  <xslFile>xsl\modifications.xsl</xslFile>
  <xslFile>xsl\compile-msbuild.xsl</xslFile>
  <xslFile>xsl\unittests.xsl</xslFile>   
  <xslFile>xsl\MsTestReport2008.xsl</xslFile>
  <xslFile>xsl\MsTestSummary.xsl</xslFile>
 </xslFiles>
</email>
```

So now I get an output of the passed and failed unit tests in the report email.